# How to rotate SurfaceView on Android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, libvlc, vlc-android

I am working with VLCAndroid library. At the beggining I used TextureView so I can rotate the player any direction I want. But the TextureView have shown poor performace and drop FPS in some old devices then I must switch back to the SurfaceView. But I cannot rotate the player any more

I have tried to set the direction of the activity by `requestOrientation()`, but the devices I work with cannot set it's direction to `REVERSE_LANDSCAPE`.

I have tried to set VLC option but it's not working either:

```
args.add("--video-filter=rotate")
args.add("--rotate-angle=180")
```

So my only option left is to rotate the SurfaceView of VLCLayout. But I tried to set its orientation by 180f but it didn't work too.

Do you know how to rotate the SurfaceView? Thank you.

Comment: can you share verbose logs please?

Comment: any solution for that? have you tried other params for VLC without touching `SurfaceView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void changeMediaPlayerLayout(int displayW, int displayH) {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isReleased()) return;
        /* Change the video placement using the MediaPlayer API */
        switch (mCurrentScaleType) {
            case SURFACE_BEST_FIT:
                mMediaPlayer.setAspectRatio(null);
                mMediaPlayer.setScale(0);
                break;
            case SURFACE_FIT_SCREEN:
            case SURFACE_FILL: {
                IMedia.VideoTrack vtrack = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentVideoTrack();
                if (vtrack == null)
                    return;
                final boolean videoSwapped = vtrack.orientation == IMedia.VideoTrack.Orientation.LeftBottom
                        || vtrack.orientation == IMedia.VideoTrack.Orientation.RightTop;
                if (mCurrentScaleType == MediaPlayer.ScaleType.SURFACE_FIT_SCREEN) {
                    int videoW = vtrack.width;
                    int videoH = vtrack.height;

                    if (videoSwapped) {
                        int swap = videoW;
                        videoW = videoH;
                        videoH = swap;
                    }
                    if (vtrack.sarNum != vtrack.sarDen)
                        videoW = videoW * vtrack.sarNum / vtrack.sarDen;

                    float ar = videoW / (float) videoH;
                    float dar = displayW / (float) displayH;

                    float scale;
                    if (dar >= ar)
                        scale = displayW / (float) videoW; /* horizontal */
                    else
                        scale = displayH / (float) videoH; /* vertical */
                    mMediaPlayer.setScale(scale);
                    mMediaPlayer.setAspectRatio(null);
                } else {
                    mMediaPlayer.setScale(0);
                    mMediaPlayer.setAspectRatio(!videoSwapped ? ""+displayW+":"+displayH
                            : ""+displayH+":"+displayW);
                }
                break;
            }
            case SURFACE_16_9:
                mMediaPlayer.setAspectRatio("16:9");
                mMediaPlayer.setScale(0);
                break;
            case SURFACE_4_3:
                mMediaPlayer.setAspectRatio("4:3");
                mMediaPlayer.setScale(0);
                break;
            case SURFACE_ORIGINAL:
                mMediaPlayer.setAspectRatio(null);
                mMediaPlayer.setScale(1);
                break;
        }
    }
```

from https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/-/blob/master/libvlc/src/org/videolan/libvlc/VideoHelper.java

you need to play with the scale and aspect ratio functions.

Comment: Can you explain more about this? How can this relate to rotating media ?

Comment: it allows to configure the video output from libvlc functions

Comment: But i can't access it because it private in VideoHelper

Comment: I tried these code but it doesnt work. Thank you.